# Ruby class to get sales tax

Tags: ruby

What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to get sales tax and eventually use it for math calculations?

```
class Item
    def initialize(type)
        @type = type
    def tax_calc(type)
        if type.include?("book")
            sales_tax = 0
        else 
            sales_tax = 2
        end
    end
end


puts "what is type"
type2 = gets


Item.new(type2)

puts sales_tax
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us how it's behaving for you, and how that is wrong compared to what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is missing an `end` and you have a nested method definition, which is a very advanced topic, and I don't see it used very often except as a toy.

This code will return the tax number.

```
class Item
  def initialize(type)
    @type = type
  end
  def tax_calc
    if @type.include("book")
      @sales_tax = 0
    else 
      @sales_tax = 2
    end
  end
  def sales_tax
    tax_calc
  end
end

puts "what is type"
type = gets

purchase = Item.new(type)
puts purchase.sales_tax
```

I changed `type2` to simply  `type` because there is no reason to worry about mirroring the local variable inside the class due to scope.

This code is far from being optimal, but it is at least 'working code'.

Comment: is this not a good setup for a tax calculation? i'm going to make it better and more complex, is this a bad basis?

Comment: Still, as the Tin Man mentioned, it is hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do.  At this point you are apparently returning a tax classification, rather than a calculation.  You will build it out and have more questions I am sure.  So, I think for where you are you are on your way.  I am positive your code will change, and likely this code will not exist as it does now and likely very soon.  You have a good start, because so far, we have not seen floats. :)

Answer (score 1):

In your code,`sales_tax` is a local variable of the `initialize` method. It doesn't exist outside of that scope.

Here's one way to get the sales tax:

```
class Item
  def initialize(type)
    @sales_tax = type.include?('book') ? 0 : 2
  end

  def sales_tax
    @sales_tax
  end
end

item = Item.new('foo')
puts Item.new('foo').sales_tax
```